# Vb.net window wont hide

Tags: vb.net

So I am working on a program that gives you the option to select whether the computer it is being run on is a Server, or a Client. When the user chooses, it is supposed to save it into the settings, and automatically go to the necessary window upon startup, hiding the original startup screen. How ever, when I start the program, it does remember that I am a Client. But it will not hide the start screen. Here is my code.

```
Public Class screenStart
Private Sub screenStart_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If My.Settings.isserver = True Then
        screenServer.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End If
    If My.Settings.isserver = False Then
        screenClient.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub optionServer_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles optionServer.Click
    My.Settings.isserver = True
    My.Settings.Save()
    screenServer.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
Private Sub optionClient_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles optionClient.Click
    My.Settings.isserver = False
    My.Settings.Save()
    screenClient.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 1):

The `Load` event fires before the form is shown, so `Hide()` has no effect.

Instead, you should change `Main()` to show the right form in the first place, so the start form is never even loaded when you don't need to.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific as to what you mean with "Main()"? And perhaps an example?

Comment: can we use screenStart_Shown() event in this case?

Answer (score 0):

make the following change in your code that will give the required out put for you.

```
   Private Sub screenStart_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
         Me.Hide()   
         If My.Settings.isserver = True Then
         screenServer.Show()      
         else
         screenClient.Show()
         End If
   End Sub
```